# Make a partition accessible to only some users

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-server-2012

I have no doubt that I'm missing something but here goes.
I created a partition on a server to keep software installs and licenses isolated in case i need them for deployment purposes.

The partition is OK, I can access it from my PC and from the server. When I try from a user workstation I get the prompt asking for credentials, which is what I want, but when I enter my credentials i get an error:

[image: screenshot]

The security tab in the partition lists my user and the Administrators group which I am a part of, and the permission level is Full Control. The other groups are Creator Owner and system.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the PCName + \ in your username.

For example, if your pcname is PC01 and your username is User, you would enter PC01\user as username.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're accessing this "partition" across the network, through the automatic administrative share (s$). Make sure the permissions for the share are correct.

In the Properties dialog for the partition, look under "Sharing" and see who has permission to browse that share, or in File Sharing in the Computer Management tool.

By default only Administrators on the server (which would include Domain/Server Admins if in a domain) can use that kind of share. When looking at file shares, always make sure both the filesystem (partition/folder) permissions and the share permissions are correct - Even if the user account has Full Control, if it doesn't even have Read on the share, you're going nowhere.

It's probably not a good idea to go tweaking that share though. It's not designed for users, so rather make a new share with your own permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what i´m trying to do is have a protected folder that if accessed wont give an error but instead ask for credentials. 
I think i can only do that with partitons.

Comment: The partition itself is not aware of authentication means (in your case, a password). It only understands permissions, and relies on the host (Windows) to do the authentication part. As far as the partition/filesystem/folder goes, it's either allowed in, or not allowed in. If the server is domain-joined and the user is in the domain too, then it won't even prompt.  

Look at the help for the `NET USE` command to see how to attach to a network share using custom credentials instead of the logged-in user.